# Bitbucket Pipeline INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES Issue

Tags: android, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-pipelines

> I generated the build(apk) using bitbucket pipeline with the help of [the link](https://github.com/uber-common/android-build-environment/blob/master/Dockerfile)
>
> While trying to run the apk I am getting this issue 
>             **INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES**. I didn't find the solution how to include default keystore file details to bitbucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fixed this issue by doing some changes in build.sh file.

```
#!/bin/bash

./gradlew $1:assembleDebug || exit 1
BRANCH_NAME=$2
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
(umask  077 ; echo $BUILD_KEY | base64 --decode > ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
TOSEND=$BITBUCKET_COMMIT
if [ "$3" == "true" ]
then

if [ "$1" == "venkat" ]
then
    ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa build@buildstore.venkat.com mkdir -p build/androidsdk/${BRANCH_NAME}/$TOSEND
    scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa venkat/build/outputs/aar/venkat-debug.aar build@buildstore.venkat.com:build/androidsdk/${BRANCH_NAME}/$TOSEND || exit 1
fi
if [ "$1" == "app" ]
then 
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa build@buildstore.venkat.com  mkdir -p build/androidtestapp/${BITBUCKET_BRANCH}/$TOSEND
scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk  build@buildstore.venkat.com:build/androidtestapp/${BITBUCKET_BRANCH}/$TOSEND || exit 1
fi
fi
```

now build is successfully generated and able to install in devices.